# Hole/Notch in Floor joist

Tags: code-compliance, floor, joists, hole, inspection

I have a floor joist that is notched about 7 inches away from the bottom plate. The joist is a 2x8 (7 1/4) The hole is about 2.25 inches so I added a sister joist and the hole in that is probably 1.8 inches. The original beam spans around 12ft however with it resting on the wall it spans 4ft where the hole is. First is this to code? If it’s not to code does adding the sister beam bring it up to code? And if not that what should I do to bring it up to code? Second will this hinder in selling a house? Below is an image
[image]

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate or re-posted question?

Comment: @SteveSh, VtC if it's a dupe. If you don't have privileges yet, at least list the question you think it's a dupe of and others will VtC as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This diagram from:

[Notching Guidelines](https://www.jlconline.com/deck-builder/rules-for-drilling-and-notching-deck-framing_o)

shows it clearly:

[image: Notching]

It appears your notch is ok.